# How do i measure the output voltage of lm35 with digital voltmeter?

Tags: measurement

I know this is a very stupid question.

Lm35 has 3 pins: Vcc, Analog output voltage, Gnd.

Is it ok to measure between analog output voltage and gnd? Im asking because Vcc and Gnd is a dc.

Comment: Measure voltage between Gnd and Analog output voltage pins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how the IC works: it outputs an analog voltage proportional to the temperature in °C. Output is 10 mV/°C, so at 20 °C you'll get 200 mV.

Connect one pin of your voltmeter (analog or digital, doesn't matter) to the output, and the other to the ground pin, because that's the reference against which you want to measure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you definitely can because the analog pin is set by the IC with respect to ground.

You probably know this but if you are going to use a voltmeter, don't touch the leads of the LM35 with the voltmeter probes directly, because if you short it, you will experience the all too familiar smell of burning electronics.

Comment: lol, i just did it. i connect the probe directly to lm35. but i think i didnt short it. thanks for the advice.